# Jenkins Issue fatal: unable to access : URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL

Tags: jenkins, groovy, gitlab, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

My problem lies in the last stage of my Jenkins Pipeline, where Jenkins is expected to commit the updated pom.xml file to our application repository hosted on GitLab.
Below are the necessary data.

**`Jenkins Console Log`**

```
Masking supported pattern matches of $PASS
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ git config --global user.email jenkins@example.com
[Pipeline] sh
+ git config --global user.name jenkins
[Pipeline] sh
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [PASS]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ git remote set-url origin https://pop:****@gitlab.com/pop/my-web-app.git
[Pipeline] echo
[Pipeline] sh
+ git add .
[Pipeline] sh
+ git commit -m ci: version bump
[detached HEAD 2e99075] ci: version bump
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
[Pipeline] sh
+ git push origin HEAD:main
fatal: unable to access 'https://gitlab.com/pop/my-web-app.git/': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 128
Finished: FAILURE
```

**`Jenkinsfile`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

library identifier: 'jenkins-shared-library@main', retriever: modernSCM(
        [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
         remote: 'https://gitlab.com/pop/jenkins-shared-lib.git',
         credentialsId: 'gitlab'
        ]
)


pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        REPO_URL = 'gitlab.com/pop/my-web-app.git'
    }

    tools {
        maven 'Maven-3.9.5'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Version Increment') {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
                        -DnewVersion=\\\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}.\\\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} \
                        versions:commit'
                    def matcher = readFile('pom.xml') =~ '<version>(.+)</version>'  
                    def version = matcher[0][1]     

                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build App') {
            steps {
                script {
                    buildJar()
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Build Docker Image & Push') {
            steps {
                script {
                    buildImage "pop/demo-app:java_maven-${IMAGE_NAME}"
                    echo 'Building Image Done'
                    dockerLogin()
                    dockerPush "pop/demo-app:java_maven-${IMAGE_NAME}"
                    echo 'Now Pushing The Image'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                script {
                    echo 'deploying docker image to EC2...'
                }
            }
        }
        stage('commit version update') {
            steps {
                script {
                    gitLogin '${REPO_URL}'
                    gitCommit()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**`Required Files from Shared Library`**

**`VersionCommit.groovy`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

package com.example

class VersionCommit implements Serializable {

    def script

    VersionCommit(script) {
        this.script = script
    }

    def gitLogin(String repoURL) {
        script.withCredentials([script.usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'gitlab', passwordVariable: 'PASS', usernameVariable: 'USER')]) {
            script.sh 'git config --global user.email "jenkins@example.com"'
            script.sh 'git config --global user.name "jenkins"'
            script.sh "git remote set-url origin https://$script.USER:$script.PASS@$repoURL"
        }
    }

    def gitCommit() {
        script.sh 'git add .'
        script.sh 'git commit -m "ci: version bump"'
        script.sh 'git push origin HEAD:main'
    }
}
```

**`gitLogin.groovy`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import com.example.VersionCommit

def call(String repoURL){
    return new VersionCommit(this).gitLogin(repoURL)
}
```

**`gitCommit.groovy`**

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

import com.example.VersionCommit

def call(){
    return new VersionCommit(this).gitCommit()
}
```

Here's what I've done so far:

The Jenkins job runs without any errors up to the final stage.
The pom.xml file is correctly updated with the new version information.
I've double-checked the GitLab credentials and SSH key configuration, and they seem to be correct.
Despite all these preparations, I'm facing an issue where the Jenkins job doesn't seem to commit the updated pom.xml to the GitLab repository. It completes the job without any errors or warnings related to the Git commit process, but when I check the GitLab repository, there are no changes reflected in the pom.xml.

I'm uncertain about what might be causing this problem. Is it a Jenkins configuration issue, a GitLab integration problem, or something else entirely? I'm open to any insights or suggestions you might have for troubleshooting and resolving this issue.

Comment: I wonder if the username or password contains illegal characters? If you can inspect the fields, it should be easy to notice if there are any special characters that would otherwise be illegal in a URL. If so: HTML encode it.

Comment: for example, if my username is `juser` and my password is `p@ssword`, then the constructed remote URL is `https://juser:p@ssword@gitlab.whatever` which is clearly not a valid URL

Comment: Where in the code is the `pom.xml` being modified? The `git add` would be idempotent if the file is unmodified.

Comment: @AdamSmith Yes my password has a # in it. Can you tell me any other way how can I make it work?

Comment: I would recommend against putting your plaintext password in your gitconfig. Can you not set up an SSH key for your jenkins server?

Comment: @AmeyMhatre as CAustin said, it's unwise to use https credentials to connect to Git in this way. However if you insist, my initial comment gives the solution -- HTML-encode your password.

Comment: @AdamSmith Can you provide me a example how to encode it using HTML If possible :)